# Function - Python Prgramming

Tags: python-3.x

Is it possible to send functions arguments by keyword in python so that the order of the argument does not matter? If so, can anybody explain me with an example?

Comment: Is there something particular in the examples in [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) (found by searching for "python keyword arguments") which is confusing?

Comment: I asked the question since I wanted explanation in detail with some simple example. The question was very much clear. There was no need to vote it negative.

Comment: OP was misinformed. keyword order does not matter already, although there is a PEP to preserve keyword order. voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just for the sake of answering, as it is said in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) (yes, you know the thing people don't read because it is hard to read):

```
def parrot(voltage, state='a stiff', action='voom', type='Norwegian Blue'):
    print("-- This parrot wouldn't", action, end=' ')
    print("if you put", voltage, "volts through it.")
    print("-- Lovely plumage, the", type)
    print("-- It's", state, "!")

parrot(1000)                                          # 1 positional argument
parrot(voltage=1000)                                  # 1 keyword argument
parrot(voltage=1000000, action='VOOOOOM')             # 2 keyword arguments
parrot(action='VOOOOOM', voltage=1000000)             # 2 keyword arguments
parrot('a million', 'bereft of life', 'jump')         # 3 positional arguments
parrot('a thousand', state='pushing up the daisies')  # 1 positional, 1 keyword
```

Comment: This is already given in the documentation. I asked the question since I wanted explanation in detail with some simple example.